# Error in Android's clearCheck() for RadioGroup?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm having an issue with RadioGroup's clearChecked(). I'm displaying a multiple choice question to the user and after the user selects an answer I check the answer, give him some feedback and then move to the next question. In the process of moving to the next question I clearCheck on the RadioGroup.

Can anyone explain to me why the onCheckedChanged method is called 3 times? Once when the change actually occurs (with the user changes), once when I clearCheck(with -1 as the selected id) and once in between (with the user changes again)?

As far as I could tell the second trigger is provoked by clearCheck. Code below:

```
private void checkAnswer(RadioGroup group, int checkedId){
    // this makes sure it doesn't blow up when the check is cleared
    // also we don't check the answer when there is no answer
    if (checkedId == -1) return;
    if (group.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) return;

    // check if correct answer
    if (checkedId == validAnswerId){
        score++;
        this.giveFeedBack(feedBackType.GOOD);
    } else {
        this.giveFeedBack(feedBackType.BAD);
    }
    // allow for user to see feedback and move to next question
    h.postDelayed(this, 800);
}

private void changeToQuestion(int questionNumber){
    if (questionNumber >= this.questionSet.size()){
        // means we are past the question set
        // we're going to the score activity
        this.goToScoreActivity();
        return;
    }
    //clearing the check
    gr.clearCheck();
    // give change the feedback back to question
    imgFeedback.setImageResource(R.drawable.question_mark); //OTHER CODE HERE
}
```

and the run method looks like this

```
public void run() {
        questionNumber++;
        changeToQuestion(questionNumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What I've discovered is that if an item is checked and you call `clearCheck()` on the radio group it will call `onCheckedChanged` twice. The first time with the id of the item that was checked and the second time with `-1`/`View.NO_ID`. IMHO, this is a bug and apparently it has been around since at least 1.6. See this google code bug report: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4785

It seems to be that the only solution is to check the actual `RadioButton.isChecked()` and test if it is true or false. This sort of defeats the purpose of the `onCheckedChanged` returning the id of the item since you now have to either keep references to those buttons or call `findViewById` every time.

I doubt they will fix this since changing it would probably break existing code in unexpected ways.

Comment: @qbeticus Thank you, I managed in the end to use a boolean variable to figure out whether the onCheckedChanged should continue to evaluate the checked option.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that this is a bug, I was suspecting it after watching radiogroup's weird behavior.

Answer (score 22):

I faced the same problem and i solved with other work-around.

1. Set CheckedChangeListener as NULL
2. Do your operation
3. Reset your OnCheckedChangeListener again

## Code snnipet :

```
rdbGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
rdbGroup.clearCheck();
rdbGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener);
```

Hope this will help ツ

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. My solution:

in procedure:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rGroup, int checkedId)
```

I check checkedId. It equals to -1 if you use clearCheck()
else it equals to selected radiogroup child